# How to define constants in Qt Creator for different Build Settings?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing an app in Qt which connects with a server. I have a production server and a preproduction server so it would be great to be able to change the URL the app use based in the build.

So, summing up, I would need the app to behave like this:

Debug configuration

```
//somewhere in a .cpp file
QString url = BASE_URL;
// url now is, for example, "preproduction_server.com"
```

Release configuration

```
//in the same .cpp file
QString url = BASE_URL;
// url now is, for example, "production_server.com"
```

Any ideas? Should I define variables in the .pro file and use them? Define them as Environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made it using `QT_NO_DEBUG`

This is how my code looks now

```
#ifdef QT_NO_DEBUG
#define BASE_URL "production_server.com"
#else
#define BASE_URL "preproduction_server.com"
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

`NDEBUG` should be defined by qmake for the release build, so you can use this:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define BASE_URL "production_server.com"
#else
#define BASE_URL "preproduction_server.com"
#endif
```

Comment: Nope, both Debug and Release builds give me `"preproduction_server.com"`

Comment: @Dr.Pelocho Then you have bigger problems since your release build is actually a debug build. You can set `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE` and `QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG` flags to differentiate between builds. If you pass `-DNDEBUG` as a flag for `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE` the above solution should work.

Comment: The builds are correct. The Debug build has the `CONFIG+=debug` in the quake build step. I finally made it by using `QT_NO_DEBUG`